# работа процессора и взаимодействие с ос

Tags: процессор

процессор выполняет команды из исполняемого файла, то есть если там какие то плохие команды ему все равно он выполнит, а тогда если это плохой исполняемый файл, например вирус, его не пропустит ОС на исполнение процессором?

Comment: Нет такого понятия - "плохие команды". Все команды хорошие. Вирус (вредоносное ПО) выполняет "хорошие" команды, но результат возможно будет не "хорошим" для пользователя.

Comment: Вопрос хороший, но задан не очень. Почитайте Таненбаум Э. - Современные операционные системы (2015)

Comment: всего 1120 страниц. начиная с середины там про организацию изоляции выполнения программ от устройств и других программ

Comment: как раз ее начал читать, и может не дошел еще до того места, а вопросы начинают возникать)